# Сортировать json-массивы по значению внутри?

Tags: javascript

Привет. Есть файл с множеством таких массивов:

```
{
    "stops_airports":[
        "LED",
        "DME"
    ],
    "carriers":[
        "S7",
        "SU",
        "U6"
    ],
    "max_stops":1,
    "is_direct":false,
    "segments_airports":[
        [
            "BAX",
            "DME"
        ],
        [
            "SVO",
            "BAX"
        ]
    ],
    "min_stop_duration":1000,
    "total_duration":1630,
    "sign":"030f1d481dd38c7a7f430fb410446eb6",
    "terms":{
        "8":{
            "unified_price":27416,
            "url":800015,
            "price":438.02,
            "currency":"usd"
        }
    },
    "max_stop_duration":1000,
    "segment_durations":[
        1380,
        250
    ],
    "validating_carrier":"U6",
    "segments_time":[
        [
            1477297800,
            1477366200
        ],
        [
            1477432200,
            1477461600
        ]
    ]
}
```

Так вот, хочу фильтровать такие массивы по значению поля `json.terms['8'].price`. При этом, число 8 совершенно случайное и может иметь любое значение от 1 до 100. Как это сделать?

Comment: число 8 случайное, но там в объекте `terms` один ключ?

Comment: @НазарКалитюк да.