# Чем сортировать многомерный json?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть многомерный json-массив, состоящий из подобных элементов:

```
{
  "manufacturer": "Apple",
  "name": "iPhone",
  "model": "7 Plus",
  "memory": [
    "32GB",
    "128GB",
    "256GB"
  ],
  "colours": [
    "Gold",
    "Silver",
    "Pink",
    "Black"
  ],
  "terms": [
    {
      "instalment_full_price": "49$/month",
      "instalment_price": 49,
      "price": 799
    }
  ]
}
```

Как можно отсортировать между собой эти элементы по возрастанию цены по значению ключа `terms[0].price`?

Comment: вот интересно. ты задавал такой вопрос 31 июля [Сортировать json-массивы по значению внутри](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700133/191482) , тебе дали ссылку на дубликат. неужели так сложно прочитать и применить? или мозг совсем  не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Функция `sort` принимает в качестве аргумента функцию, которая в свою очередь получает 2 элемента. Их нужно сравнить и вернуть -1, 0 или 1. Подробнее на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
const arr = [
{
  "manufacturer": "Apple",
  "name": "iPhone",
  "model": "7 Plus",
  "memory": [
    "32GB",
    "128GB",
    "256GB"
  ],
  "colours": [
    "Gold",
    "Silver",
    "Pink",
    "Black"
  ],
  "terms": [
    {
      "instalment_full_price": "49$/month",
      "instalment_price": 49,
      "price": 7992
    }
  ]
},
{
  "manufacturer": "Apple",
  "name": "iPhone",
  "model": "7 Plus",
  "memory": [
    "32GB",
    "128GB",
    "256GB"
  ],
  "colours": [
    "Gold",
    "Silver",
    "Pink",
    "Black"
  ],
  "terms": [
    {
      "instalment_full_price": "49$/month",
      "instalment_price": 49,
      "price": 7991
    }
  ]
},
{
  "manufacturer": "Apple",
  "name": "iPhone",
  "model": "7 Plus",
  "memory": [
    "32GB",
    "128GB",
    "256GB"
  ],
  "colours": [
    "Gold",
    "Silver",
    "Pink",
    "Black"
  ],
  "terms": [
    {
      "instalment_full_price": "49$/month",
      "instalment_price": 49,
      "price": 79956
    }
  ]
},
{
  "manufacturer": "Apple",
  "name": "iPhone",
  "model": "7 Plus",
  "memory": [
    "32GB",
    "128GB",
    "256GB"
  ],
  "colours": [
    "Gold",
    "Silver",
    "Pink",
    "Black"
  ],
  "terms": [
    {
      "instalment_full_price": "49$/month",
      "instalment_price": 49,
      "price": 7995
    }
  ]
}
]

const newArr = arr.sort((a,b) => a.terms[0].price > b.terms[0].price)
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: boolean? *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: Спасибо за код. Странно, но в моём случае не сработало сравнение `a > b`, а сработало сравнение `a - b`.